# Sanitize WordPress Array Input?

Tags: plugin-development, wp-insert-post, sanitization

I have a form that submits the data in array format. I have sanitized all the data and also tried to escape it using `esc_attr`, but it is a function of escaping and not sanitizing.

Is there a better way to sanitize the entire array (with text value) instead of each individual value.

`$array = array_map( 'esc_attr', $array );`

How can we make sure the data is sanitize and not just escaped?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure what you mean to do, but are you looking for [`sanitize_text_field`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_text_field/)?

```
$array = array_map( 'sanitize_text_field', $array );
```

Comment: Thanks @cjbj for your reply but this is not i am looking for. I have created a plugin and it is rejected because of using "esc_attr" to sanitize. They mentioned you have to sanitize the array and not just escap the tags.